# C++: Disabling scrolling in a console application..?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, winapi, console, cmd

I have created a borderless (and scrollbox-less) console application, but I have found that if the user has a touchpad and tries to scroll the console with it, he is able to do so. (Can't be done with a regular mouse, apparently.)

I'd like to disable this feature.

First I thought about creating some kind of message handling system for a my console, just like in Win32 GUI programming, but that seemed unnecessarily difficult.

I also thought about changing the buffer size, but I have no idea how to do that (I looked into SetConsoleScreenBufferSize but couldn't do anything useful with it).

Any suggestions?

Comment: Changing the buffer size would do it

Comment: You might be running into this: *The specified dimensions also cannot be less than the minimum size allowed by the system. This minimum depends on the current font size for the console (selected by the user) and the SM_CXMIN and SM_CYMIN values returned by the GetSystemMetrics function.* You'd most likely have to set those as something lower in order to be able to set the buffer size to the window size (meaning there would be nowhere to scroll to).

Comment: Well I used _GetSystemMetrics()_ to figure out the _SM_CXMIN_ and _SM_CYMIN_ and then set the buffer size by using _SetConsoleScreenBufferSize(hWnd, bufferSize)_, where _bufferSize_ is _COORD bufferSize = {97, 28} //the values from GetSystemMetrics()_ but nothing changed. Any help?

Comment: If you output the numbers from 1-30, do 1 and 2 disappear off the top after doing that?

Comment: The last number I can see is 6.

Comment: Well, that's good. I presume you had some added "Press any key to continue." etc. at the bottom. It's normally 300. Since you can't change the minima, perhaps you can just make the window size barely big enough instead.

Comment: I think one of us misunterstood the other one. When I say that the last number I see is 6, I mean that I can see the 6, and if I use the mousepad to scroll up, I can see 1-5 too. Also, I can scroll down, even if there's no output written (just scroll the emptiness of the console). This is the problem. I know how to change the height of the console window, that's not what I want right now.

Comment: Sounds like an abuse of consoles!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem fixed..

I had accidentally used `SetConsoleScreenBufferSize(hWnd, dwSize);` instead of `SetConsoleScreenBufferSize(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), dwSize);`

EDIT: There is a small bug still.
Even when I set the `Console Screen Buffer Size` to as tiny as it can be, the user can still scroll a few steps up (to scroll back down, the user needs to be scrolling really fast, for some reason) I have no idea what might be causing this, so if you have any ideas pelase let me know.