# How to stop the console from scrolling when new text is added?(C/C++)

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

Is there a way to stop my console application from scrolling when new text is added?
In my application, I am adding new text and I don't want the console to scroll to the bottom each time that happens, I just want it to stay at the top the whole time.

This is for Windows, using the Win API.

Comment: No. There is nothing controlling vertical scrolling in C or C++. You'll have to use platform specific functions or libraries to do that

Comment: For Windows see [1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12994296)
[2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3471520)
[3](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25432474)

 for a start.

Comment: Which operating system?

Comment: @user202729 Those that you sent only show how to remove scrolling, I don't want to do that, I just want the console screen to to stay at the top of the console when new text is added because when new text is added the console screen scrolls to the bottom of that text. This is for Windows.

Comment: Maybe take a look at [4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60167843/how-to-keep-text-at-the-top-of-console) (although I'm not sure about whether there may be some flicker) [5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31740747/system-console-as-a-log-window-with-input-line) or ncurses/other console manipulation libraries.

Comment: I think this is possible with [WriteConsoleOutput](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/writeconsoleoutput), since it doesn't change the cursor position.

Comment: @ssbssa I think ```WriteConsoleOutput()``` might be the way to go, although I am having trouble figuring out how to use it with a ```DWORD``` since the parameters require a ```const void*``` as the characters that will be outputted.

Comment: Where do you see that `const void*`? The characters should be in `const CHAR_INFO *`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try writing `system("cls");` to clear the screen and write from the top again.

Comment: Note `cls` is specific to Windows

Comment: Ok didn't know that, but they are using Windows.

Comment: The OP doesn't want to clear the console just to keep it from scrolling. They want to retain whatever is there. Besides, `system` isn't part of the Windows API. It's [part](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/program/system) of the C Standard Library. And likely the worst option to ever consider. Launching a process just to clear the console is mighty wasteful. Especially, since there is a dedicated [console API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/console-functions) readily available.

Comment: Alright thank you for the info.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using printf

1. Do not end your lines with \n
2. Start each line with \r.  This will cause the program to continuously overwrite the line where you first started printing
3. Add a fflush to flush the buffer

If you're using std::cout,

1. Do not end your lines with std::endl
2. Start each line wiht \r
3. Add std::flush at the end of line

The only problem is that if the new line is shorter than the previous line, the  text may not be overwritten.